# Contract events logs: string data field divided

Tags: solidity, events, bscscan

I got this event signature:

```
event Event(address indexed from, address indexed to, string text);
```

Which I call inside this method:

```
function emitEvent(address to, string calldata text) external {
    emit Event(msg.sender, to, text);
}
```

Once I call the function **EmitEvent**, the data field in logs appears to be split in three different pieces:
[image: logs screenschot]

Topics are correct: the event signature and the from and to addresses.

However, the data field is divided in 3 instead of just one string (I sent the **"Hello world"** text as you can see).
Where does the previous data information come from? The number 32 and 11?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Francesco,

Data layout here is the following:

- slot0: 32 (0x20) is the data offset, basically this points to the
- slot1 (each slot is 32 bytes long) slot1: 11 is the length of the string "Hello world" (actually underlying bytes array)
- slot2: "Hello world" string (48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6C 64)

String is stored as a dynamic array and thus needs offset and length be present.

See also:

1. Similar question, but here the string is stored in slot2, and the offset is 64 (0x40): [can anyone explain the format of this input string to a function?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50585/can-anyone-explain-the-format-of-this-input-string-to-a-function)
2. https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/abi-spec.html#use-of-dynamic-types

Note also that if the string contains non-ASCII characters, the length becomes bigger than just number of characters in the string, since some characters require more than 1 byte.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!